# Word to describe required attitude for a comparison between circumstance

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

> Jesus lives in a Venezuela. He saves 30% of his salary and lives lean without spending much money on himself. He practices what he read from his favorite American motivational books. Every year Jesus looks at how his country's currency depreciation devalues his savings and that his savings are less than it was the previous year in purchasing power despite him adding 30% of his annual salary to it.
>
> Jesus comes to the realization that his previous belief of saving his money is counterproductive. He also realizes American motivation books on saving are not applicable to his situation. He instead needs to re-evaluate his deep seated belief of becoming wealthy through saving and find another way to achieve success as his current belief of wealth and goals is moving him one step forward but two steps back
>
> An American women comments he should relax more like her? He replies he rather needs  *perspective* to adjust to a new plan of action due to the circumstance of his times which are not applicable to her. He says he has to adjust his attitude and work harder and smarter without being complacent and common sense complacency will lead him to failure and not being able to retire ever. He wants to tell her he has to work twice as hard as her to get a fifth of what she has. He wants a word to describe this.

The word *perspective* doesn't convey what I want to say as to me it feels like a personal change of attitude or view where as I want to convey it as he is adjusting to his situation of the day. Also it's not that his view of success was bad as saving is good for most people.

*Foresight*  or *reflection* also doesn't fit in as for him it is more common sense action but since losing money when saving is not common sense you can't call him common sense.

I couldn't think of a word where he has to work much harder than someone in the US. A word that conveys the attitude he needs to take. He has no choice. He has to take that attitude.

Comment: Does *resolve* work for you?  The firm determination to do something.
"she received information that strengthened her resolve"

Comment: Not quite as I want to covey a different of attitude rather than a strengthening of it.

Comment: He's come to the *realisation* that he needs to rethink his attitude?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He perhaps has to adopt a ***pragmatic*** attitude (or ***pragmatism***, for short).

ODO:

> **[pragmatic](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pragmatic)**
>
> *ADJECTIVE*
>
> **1** Dealing with things sensibly and realistically in a way that is based
>   on practical rather than theoretical considerations:
>
> ‘a pragmatic approach to politics’
>
> ‘He was highly practical and would come up with pragmatic solutions on
>   various issues.’
>
> ‘As I read history, most of the founders were sensible and pragmatic
>   men rather than visionary idealists.’
>
> **[pragmatism](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pragmatism)**
>
> *NOUN*
>
> **1** A pragmatic attitude or policy:
>
> ‘ideology had been tempered with pragmatism’

In this context, the *theory* is not the *American way* that he was reading on (it may after all be what actually worked in the US). Instead, the (underlying) theory that he is trying to debunk is, "*what worked in the US will work elsewhere*".

Comment: I like this.  Related to this, Juan has to be a *realist*.

Comment: @aparente001 Ditto.

Answer (score 1):

Jesus needs to ***resign himself*** (to his circumstances).

From [Cambridge Dictionaries](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/resign-yourself-to-sth):

> **resign yourself to sth**
>   — phrasal verb with resign UK ​ /rɪˈzaɪn/ US ​ /rɪˈzaɪn/ verb [ I or T ]
>   C2 **to make yourself accept something
>   that you do not like because you cannot change it**:
>   [ + -ing verb ] *He
>   resigned himself to liv**ing** alone.*

In this case, Jesus can't change the realities of Venezuela's economy that make the standard North American advice about saving unworkable, so he has to accept what he's actually dealing with and make a different plan.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps Jesus needs to adjust his *mindset*.

M-W:

> [*mindset*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mindset): a
>   mental attitude or inclination; a fixed state of mind

Your example:

> "An American women comments he should relax more like her? He replies
>   he rather needs *to change his mindset* and adjust to a new plan of
>   action due to the circumstance of his times which are not applicable
>   to her."

His old *mindset* -- his fixed state of mind based on his assumptions about reality -- just won't work for his circumstances as he now understands them. He's realized that he needs to change his *mindset* to realize his goals.

Answer (score 0):

He needs to be adaptable

> *[adaptable](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/adaptable)* - able to adjust oneself readily to different conditions:
>   an adaptable person.

From [biology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptation):

> An *adaptive* trait is an aspect of the developmental pattern of the organism which enables or enhances the probability of that organism surviving and reproducing

Answer (score 0):

He needs to be [resilient](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/resilient)

> tending to recover from or adjust easily to misfortune or change